# How to screenshot or pipe the output from xscreensaver?

Tags: xorg, screenshot, xscreensaver

Some outputs are really great, IMHO.

I have read all xscreensaver manual, but I cannot get it to work so I run a xscreensaver animation and then get a PNG (or TIF, or whatever).

How can I make a virtual display so it can be screenshot? Or maybe can I somehow pipe out the output to a PNG/TIF file?

Or is it possible to run each animation as standalone command?

Comment: You can run xscreensaver as regular window and just use your favorite screenshot program to take pictures. Also, programs often have toned triggers for screenshots. For example, in gimp you can wait 15 s before it takes a screenshot of you fill in the respective fields in the screenshotting dialog

Comment: Thanks, @MarcusMüller! It was simple to use your GIMP method. 

But, I didn't run xscreensaver as a regular window. How do I do that? Because when I run the xscreensaver-settings, then click on Demo button, I get a fullscreen screensaver "window", not a regular window that I can switch in and off as usual. It was the only way I could achieve the result.

Comment: find the actual individual screensaver programs and run them! Mine (on my system, fedora) are in /usr/libexec/xscreensaver/. For example, running `/usr/libexec/xscreensaver/pong` I get it in a normal window, anyways. However, if that doesn't work for you, you might need to specify that you want that, `-window`: `/usr/libexec/xscreensaver/pong -window`

Comment: I feel so dumb! You are absolutely right, @MarcusMüller! I appreciate a lot your patience ;D
I had this idea that running a screensaver module will necessarily run as a screensaver and not as a regular window. Thanks again!

Comment: You're absolutely not dumb! None of this is intuitive it can be known without knowing the programs or how some developers more than thirty years ago thought you should do Fullscreen graphics

Comment: :D Thanks again!